# concurrent process for restoring object in s3 using python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I would like to process the logic in parallel.

The object is stored in the `s3` and I want it to be restored by calling `boto's` api.

Below is my whole code.

```
import concurrent
import boto3
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def restore_obj(bucket, key, start, end):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    for i in range(start, end):
        target = f"{key}/dummy_{i}.parquet"
        print(target)
        s3.restore_object(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Key=target,
            RestoreRequest={
                'Days': 1,
                'GlacierJobParameters': {
                    'Tier': 'Standard',
                },
            },
        )


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.Executor() as executor:
        bucket = 'dev-sclee01-ap-northeast-1'
        prefix = 'deep-glacier-dummy'
        futures = []
        futures.append(executor.submit(restore_obj(bucket, prefix, 0, 10)))
        futures.append(executor.submit(restore_obj(bucket, prefix, 10, 20)))

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            result = future.result()
            print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, I separated two parts such as `range(0,10)` and `range(10,20)` and ran them in parallel.

However, I found that the console showed me that the error has been thrown.
Moreover, the result looks like not in parallel. It tried to process the `range(0,10)` part and do not process second part by seeing the console log.

Can you give me any solutions for this to run them in parallel?

```
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_0.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_1.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_2.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_3.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_4.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_5.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_6.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_7.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_8.parquet
deep-glacier-dummy/dummy_9.parquet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sclee01/PycharmProjects/awsboto/async_boto.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/sclee01/PycharmProjects/awsboto/async_boto.py", line 49, in main
    futures.append(executor.submit(restore_obj(bucket, prefix, 0, 10)))
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 580, in submit
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: In your calls to submit, you have actually called the `restore_obj(bucket, prefix, X, Y)` function instead of passing the name of the function `restore_obj` and the parameters to be passed (for later execution). See the `pow` example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).